# iphone git clone three20 project host unreachable

Tags: iphone, xcode, git, three20, host

I am simply trying to do step one here on how to add There20 to my project: [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20)

However when I run this on my terminal: `git clone git://github.com/facebook/three20.git`, it says:

```
Cloning into three20...
fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

I also tried with `git://github.com/facebook/three20.git`, this opens `Xcode` but gives host unreachable.

I can of course access github.com.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall that blocks port 9418? Try to telnet github.com on this port. If you get a timeout, this port is likely blocked.

Comment: @tilo Yes, I think that is the problem the company firewall is blocking that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using https protocol instead:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/three20.git
```

You may be behind a firewall that is blocking access via the git protocol.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but tried that and got Cloning into three20...
error: Couldn't resolve host 'github.com' while accessing https://github.com/facebook/three20.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

Comment: It's something with your network then. It just worked OK for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
git clone git@github.com:facebook/three20.git
```

I had a similar issue with a submodule setup. I changed the config file such that the submodule URL is in this format, excluding the protocol prefix and turning the user name into something like a port number. This worked for me.